# How to copy font name in Windows11

Tags: css, windows, fonts, system

For example I have a font file installed in Win11, and I want to copy its font name so I can write CSS with less mistakes.
How do I copy the font name in the plan text?

I tried in

settings > fonts > certain fonts

and

left click the font file> properties

Everything is unclickable.

Answer (score 0):

I like working with PowerShell, so I'll help in this way. Using PS you can get the list of fonts and copy from the PS window. Commands:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
(New-Object System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection).Families
```